# Delphi XE4 iOS gestures not working

Tags: ios, delphi, gestures

I can not gety gestures to work.

**myTImage** has set property **GestureManager** to **myTGestureManager**. **myTImage** has event handler **onGesture** set to **HandleGestures**. However, the code is never run when performing zoom functions on macbook / iOS simulator (even though documentation says it should work as far as I read)

Comment: I'm not familiar with iOS, but I fear you're misunderstanding what the gesture manager is for. You need a gesture manager for recognizing special gestures like drawing a pyramid, a Z character or something like that. When you want to perform the typical "Pinch and spread" zoom gesture with two fingers - That's an "interactive gesture". You may not have a gesture manager assigned for a component if you want those to work. What you're looking for is the interactive gesture `igZoom`.

Comment: I believe I have done like described in this Delphi tutorial: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en ... however, I had not noticed that I on iOS do not need GestureManager for this... (Mentioned at bottom of article) Hmmm I will try again and report back :)

Comment: In case you mean [this one](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Gestures_in_FireMonkey) it says "_If you are working with an iOS application, start at step 3 (assigning a GestureManager is not part of enabling interactive gestures for iOS)._"

Comment: That was the one. It still does not work though. I step-3) check zoom + pan. I then step-4) listen to OnGesture event, but it never fires. At least not when running in simulator. (I hold down "alt" button that brings up the zoom simulator functionality)

Comment: Does anyone know of any working demo/example, so I can see from that what is wrong? Maybe image alignment or other things affect if the event fires?

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful If you make an aswer, I will accept it and give bounty. I fond that zoom now works on iPhone, but not working on Macbook iOs simulator. Not sure why, maybe my mistake. I have still have troubles with panning, but oh well :)

Comment: For reference I opened a question regarding panning here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907730/delphi-ios-and-pan-gesture-distance-always-zero with my working zoom code and non-working pan code.

Comment: I don't think making an answer out of a simple comment would be appropriate since I still have absolutely no clue why it would work on a real world device, but not the simulator. And that was the question. Gestures work. But not on the simulator you say.