# Delphi iOS zoom + pan at same time (two fingers not let go off screen at the same time)

Tags: ios, delphi

I have this code:

```
  case EventInfo.GestureID of
    igiZoom:
      begin
        if
          (not(TInteractiveGestureFlag.gfEnd in EventInfo.Flags))
        then
          begin
            if (not(TInteractiveGestureFlag.gfBegin in EventInfo.Flags)) then
              begin
                W := LImage.Width + 2 * ((EventInfo.Distance - FMapsLastDistanceZoom) / 3);
                H := LImage.Height + 2 * ((EventInfo.Distance - FMapsLastDistanceZoom) / 3);
                if
                  (W < layoutMapsContent.Width)
                or
                  (H < layoutMapsContent.Height)
                then
                  begin
                    W := layoutMapsContent.Width;
                    H := layoutMapsContent.Height;
                  end
                ;
                LImage.Width := W;
                LImage.Height := H;
              end
            ;
            FMapsLastDistanceZoom := EventInfo.Distance;
          end
        ;
      end
    ;
    igiPan:
      begin
        if
          (not(TInteractiveGestureFlag.gfEnd in EventInfo.Flags))
        then
          begin
            if (not(TInteractiveGestureFlag.gfBegin in EventInfo.Flags)) then
              begin
                LImage.Position.X := LImage.Position.X + (EventInfo.Location.X - FMapsLastPositionPan.X);
                LImage.Position.Y := LImage.Position.Y + (EventInfo.Location.Y - FMapsLastPositionPan.Y);
              end
            ;
            FMapsLastPositionPan.X := EventInfo.Location.X;
            FMapsLastPositionPan.Y := EventInfo.Location.Y;
          end
        ;
      end
    ;
    igiDoubleTap:
      begin
        UpdateMapsPosition;
      end
    ;
  end;
```

However, because zoom uses 2 fingers, the panning sometimes get messed up if one finger is removed slightly before the other (image jumps to the "last" finger performing the zoom while image was panned)

Is there any way to solve that?

Comment: I only have a single-touch enabled display so I can't really test the multitouch gestures. You should try to find out in which order stuff happens: (igiZoom/[gfBegin]), (igiZoom/[]), (igiZoom/[gfEnd]), (igiPan/[gfBegin]), (igiPan/[]), (igiPan/[gfInertia]), (igiPan/[gfEnd]). This is what I would expect. Does it happen in this order? Apart from that, you could code it yourself: What is `EventInfo.Location` for the zoom and for the pan gesture? If they're identical, you could identify this case this way.

Comment: Not sure I read you entreily correct, but the problem is I can not differentiate: 1) When the first finger is released, a normal igiPan (with neither gfEnd/gfBegin) event is generated. 2) When the last finger is released, igiPan / gfEnd event is generated... Both these events pass location information of the last finger

Comment: Should note that there is no problem if both fingers are released within same ~0.1 second. But normal use has shown that is too fast. If there was a way to increase that period, then that would count as a solution as well

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am facing the exact issue.

Comment: @PranoyC In the end I changed to Swift. However, will keep question up if anyone finds an answer.

Comment: In Swift, I was facing a similar problem, and I solved it by ensuring that panning took place only when there were two fingers touching.